# 次のようなtableをcontent_tagを用いてhelperとして作成したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails で次のようなtableの表を作成する際、いつもif文を用いて実装しております。
※ slimで記載しております

categories/index.html.slim

```
- if store.categorys.present?
  - store.categorys.each do |category|
      tr
        td = category.id
        td = category.name
        td = link_to '編集', new_store_category_path(store.id)
- else
  td
  td
  td = link_to '新規作成', new_store_category_path(store.id)
```

これで意図した表は作成できており、今回のようにtdの数が少ない時はいいのですが、tdの数が10個近くあるようなtableを作成する場合、可読性がかなり悪くなります。

これを何とかリファクタリングしたいと思い調べたところ、content_tagを用いたヘルパーを使えば実現できるのかもしれないというところまでわかり、content_tagを用いたサンプルコードなどを用いて色々と試しておりました。

しかし、上手くいかず、困っております。

目的としては、複数箇所でこういったif文での分岐で、使いわけるtableのリファクタリングです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

コメントではコードが書けないので、回答側で失礼しますが、質問です。
リファクタリングしたい、ということですが、範囲が広く求めているゴールが分かりませんでした。
問題意識が下記であれば、繰り返しを使って、まとめれば良いのではないかしら？と思います。

> tdの数が10個近くあるようなtableを作成する場合、可読性がかなりわるくなります。

```
- if store.categorys.present?
  - store.categorys.each do |category|
    tr
      td = category.id
      td = category.name
      td = link_to '編集', new_store_category_path(store.id)
- else
  - 2.times.each do 
    td
  td = link_to '新規作成', new_store_category_path(store.id)
```

2つなので、`2.times`ですが、10個なら、`10.times`が使えると思います。
この問題だけでしたら、シンプルに回答できてしまいますので、より具体的なイメージ、擬似コードなどを追加していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

10.times
でtdが作成できるのは私にはなかった発想でしたので、とても参考になりました。

以下のように、複雑なtableを作成するときに、if文がネストすることもあり、できるだけ、if文を無くせるところは無くせるようにしたいと考え、helperに移したいと考えました。



- if store.categorys.present?
  - store.categorys.each do |category|
    tr
      td = category.id
      td = 
        - if category.users
        xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxxxx
      td = link_to '編集', new_store_category_path(store.id)
- else
  - 2.times.each do 
    td
  td = link_to '新規作成', new_store_category_path(store.id)

Comment: 作成したい helpr の定義を書くことができるでしょうか？ 引数は、何で、どのような返り値になるかです。それがわかれば、書き方についてはご相談に乗れると思います

Answer (score 0):

helper を用意しなくても次のように String の乗算演算子を使って簡潔に記述できます。

```
- if store.categorys.present?
  - store.categorys.each do |category|
      tr
        td = category.id
        td = category.name
        td = link_to '編集', new_store_category_path(store.id)
- else
  == content_tag(:td) * 2
  td = link_to '新規作成', new_store_category_path(store.id)
```

繰り返す数は掛ける数（上記では 2 ）を変えるだけです。
ただし、slim の `==` 表記（rawヘルパーと同等）を使っていることに注意してください。

もしどうしてもヘルパー化したい場合は、そのままメソッド化することもできます。

helpers/table_helper.rb

```
module TableHelper
  def empty_td(count=1)
    raw(content_tag(:td) * count)
  end
end
```

views/categories/index.html.slim

```
- if store.categorys.present?
  - store.categorys.each do |category|
      tr
        td = category.id
        td = category.name
        td = link_to '編集', new_store_category_path(store.id)
- else
  = empty_td(2)
  td = link_to '新規作成', new_store_category_path(store.id)
```